# Probability of picking more balls of one color

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you flip a 3-sided coin $n$ times. The sides are denoted: $A$, $B$, and $C$. The probability of a coin flip turning one of the sides is given by $p_A$, $p_B$, and $p_C$, respectively.

What is the probability that you end up flipping side $A$ more times than side $B$?

---

I know this looks like a homework problem, but it is not. It is a rewording of a problem I ran into in my research. It looks easy, but I am having trouble getting it started. Any hints would be very welcome.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you, I decided to clarify it a bit more by changing the example a bit. Even with replacement, the urn problem usually equates probabilities with proportions.

Comment: All possible outcomes, with their probabilities, are given by the expression $(p_A x + p_B y + p_C z)^n$, where the coefficient of each term $x^i y^j z^k$ (namely $\binom{n}{i,j,k}$) is the probability of getting $i$ $A$s, $j$ $B$s and $k$ $C$s (note that we have $i + j + k = n$). So we want the sum of coefficients in which $i > j$. As we don't care about $C$s we could set $z=1$, but it doesn't really simplify by much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of flipping side $A$ $j$ times and side $B$ $k$ times is
$$\frac{n!}{j!k!(n-j-k)!}p_A^jp_B^kp_C^{n-j-k}$$
and so the probability that you flip $A$ more than you flip $B$ is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^n\frac{n!}{j!k!(n-j-k)!}p_A^jp_B^kp_C^{n-j-k}.$$
This does not strike me as a very useful expression. Assuming $p_A<p_B$, you should be able to use Stirling's formula to prove an asymptotic of the form $e^{-n\alpha}$ for some $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Thank you. Just a small thing: I think the outside summation should end at $n/2$ or $(n-1)/2$, whichever one is even.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is $1$ if p(A) > p(B) otherwise it is $0$.

**EDIT**

My answer above was based on the first version of this question.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Suppose $n=1$, and $p_A>p_B>0$. Then, there is still a chance of picking a ball of type $B$...

Comment: If $n=1$ the urn only has one ball  and so one of the three probabilities will be $1$ and the other two will be $0$.

Comment: The idea is that you don't know what is inside the urn. You only know the probabilities.

Comment: But the probabilities directly reflect how many balls of each type are in the urn.

Comment: @Jens I think instead we are thinking of flipping a 3-sided coin $n$ times, and the urn formulation is misleading.

Comment: Agreed, I will change the setup to a three sided coin.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The setup was indeed misleading before.